# CSS display vertical scrollbar on pre tag

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I am trying to get the vertical scrollbar to show in Chrome `running latest version 21` when the content of a `pre` tag overflows. I can't get the vertical scrollbar to actually display though.

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/justink101/2tJmC/

**EDIT**

On Mac - OSX

Comment: which version of chrome exactly ? i'm getting the scrollbar on chrome v21.0.1180.89 m

Comment: yeah, same here using v21 chrome

Comment: I see the scrollbar in that fiddle.

Comment: `Version 21.0.1180.89` Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/MfT01.png

Comment: there is no style called `overflow-y:none;`, why is it there in you CSS ?

Comment: I don't see the scrollbar, even setting `overflow-y:scroll;`. *Craaazy*.

Comment: Wow, I can replicate the issue. No idea what's going on!

Comment: @SreenathSoman :D i can't believe you just say that!

Comment: @Gustonez sorry for being delusional ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-y , I can't see any `none` option in there.

Comment: Oh yeah i thought you meant the `overflow-y`

Answer (score 34):

http://jsfiddle.net/UTYzd/

you are loading css from external file: bootstrap-combined.min.css
try to change the following:

`word-break` `word-wrap` `white-space`

```
pre {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    word-break: normal !important;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
    white-space: pre !important;
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try and wrap the 'pre' section tags with a 'div', and apply the CSS on that div.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utkai/2tJmC/2/).